# Install Pyicu in python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

My system is Windows 10 x64

Now I would like to install pyicu but I encounter with a problem like this

```
Collecting pyicu
```

Using cached PyICU-1.9.7.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\ANHVU\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-v5fb9ri4\pyicu\setup.py", line 12, in 
        ICU_VERSION = os.environ['ICU_VERSION']
      File "C:\Users\ANHVU\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\os.py", line 725, in **getitem**
        raise KeyError(key) from None
    KeyError: 'ICU_VERSION'

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ANHVU\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-v5fb9ri4\pyicu\setup.py", line 26, in <module>
    ICU_VERSION = check_output(('icu-config', '--version')).strip()
  File "C:\Users\ANHVU\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\subprocess.py", line 316, in check_output
    **kwargs).stdout
  File "C:\Users\ANHVU\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\subprocess.py", line 383, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\Users\ANHVU\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\subprocess.py", line 676, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\ANHVU\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\subprocess.py", line 955, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ANHVU\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-v5fb9ri4\pyicu\setup.py", line 33, in <module>
    ''')
RuntimeError:
Please set the ICU_VERSION environment variable to the version of
ICU you have installed.
```

How can I resolve this? Help me pls.

Answer (score 22):

You can download a corresponding whl file from [GitHub repo](https://github.com/cgohlke/pyicu-build/releases) <s>[Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyicu)</s>

For example, the latest version (as of Jan 13 2019) for your 64-bit Windows and Python3.7 version is PyICU‑2.2‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl

Then open the Windows Powershell console as Administrator, cd to the directory where you put the whl file and execute the following command:

```
python -m pip install .\PyICU‑2.2‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl
```

or (if you already have a previous PyICU version installed)

```
python -m pip install -U .\PyICU‑2.2‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl
```

Comment: The " Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages" no longer works: *The page or document cannot be found*

Comment: It seems that the coauthor of _Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages_ - `gohlke` - moved it to his GitHub repository: https://github.com/cgohlke/pyicu-build

Answer (score 0):

For the record:

My system (Win 10, 64 bit, python 3.8) gave me the exact same error message.

The solution was to install the 32-bit version of the PyICU whl file, not the 64 bit version.