# How to install dataset on Windows?

Tags: python, dataset

After installing Anaconda 4.3 which come with pre-installed Python 3.6 and pandas 0.19.12, i want to install dataset but couldn't make it possible.

I tried many different solutions, for example

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
easy_install -U setuptools
pip install ez_setup
pip install --upgrade setuptools --user python
```

None worked. I still got this error

```
  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\khoithinh\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-install-tew9mnv7\pyicu\setup.py", line 53, in <module>
        ''')
    RuntimeError:
    Please set the ICU_VERSION environment variable to the version of
    ICU you have installed.


    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\khoithinh\AppData\Local\Temp\2\pip-install-tew9mnv7\pyicu\
```

Comment: What do you mean by "dataset"? Also, Anaconda is a distribution of Python so it's not clear to me why you also downloaded 3.6, unless you're saying that this is the version of Python that came with Anaconda

Comment: Most people who use "datasets" do so through the `pandas` package, which comes preinstalled with Anaconda. A dataset is a data structure within `pandas`, not a package of its own. Do you mean something else?

Comment: Sorry for my unclear question. Anaconda 4.3 come with pre-installed Python 3.6

Comment: @RoryDaulton i checked all modules using "conda list" but didn't see any dataset. I did see pandas though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better recap of what you're trying to achieve could be useful. What's the "above exception" mentioned? What's the initial command you ran? *Is the `ICU_VERSION` environment variable set up in Windows?*

Anyways, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46871401/install-pyicu-in-python-3-x) post and [this](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyicu) link on how to setup ICU on Windows, it should provide some pointers.